# Finding even cycle in directed graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, graph-theory

Given a directed graph, we want to decide whether it contains a directed cycle of even length. This 1997 paper by [YUSTER and ZWICK](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/eric.thierry/Graphes2010/yz97.pdf) states that the problem is not known to be in $P$ nor is it known to be $NP$-complete.

> Is there any recent result that resolves the complexity of the even cycle problem in directed graphs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, a polynomial time algorithm was first given in:

Neil Robertson, P. D. Seymour, Robin Thomas. "Permanents, Pfaffian orientations, and even directed circuits." Annals of Mathematics 150.3 (1999): 929-975. [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.CO/9911268)

edit: Actually, according to the acknowledgements section of the above paper, the result was first obtained by McCuaig who later published it as:

William McCuaig. "Pólya's Permanent Problem." Electr. J. Comb. 11(1) (2004) http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i1r79

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Nice topological characterization.